# How to use wevtutil.exe command lines in a Process?

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, event-log

This is two functions im using the wevtutil in both functions this arguments worked in a bat file but not working here i cant find any of the text files created in the contentDirectory.
Something is wrong with the Arguments i guess.

```
private void SystemEvents()
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = contentDirectory;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "wevtutil qe system /rd:true /f:text> eventsys.txt";
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();
        }


private void AppEvents()
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = contentDirectory;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "wevtutil qe application /rd:true /f:text> eventapp.txt";
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();
        }
```

What is wrong with the arguments ?

Comment: Are you running your program as Administrator?

Comment: Yes i do. I run the visual studio as admin already. And im using other programs exe through cmd that need admin and they are working.

Answer (score 0):

your cmd.exe is missing a /c agument. type `cmd.exe /?` in a termainal for more info.

you could just change the Arg line too:

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c wevtutil qe application /rd:true /f:text";
```

but really I guess you want to do something like this instead.

```
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "wevtutil";
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;            
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "qe application /rd:true /f:text";
```

Then redirect stdout/stderr to allow you to process the output in C#.